# List all processes that currently running on windows by VB.NET 2.0

Tags: vb.net

In my program, i need to List up all processes that currently running on windows by VB.NET framework 2.0.

Can i get this list with VB.NET coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Process.GetProcesses` function

try this code.

```
    For Each OneProcess As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        ListBox1.Items.Add(OneProcess.ProcessName)
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Imports System.Diagnostics.
Dim p As Process
For Each p In Process.GetProcesses
 Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a VB guy but try

```
Dim localAll As Process() = Process.GetProcesses()
```

and some possible imports:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.ComponentModel
```

info from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9.aspx

Comment: dang... folks are on it this morning... 2 other answers in the time it took me to write mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Process.GetProcesses()
```

in `System.Diagnostics`

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)